# How do allow "make" to run after I have run CMake and zipped/moved the entire project to a different location?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I'm a student and we are building a VM as a part of my class. I decided I wanted to use CMake instead of writing raw Makefiles. My Teacher does not want to run `cmake` when running our project. I need to zip my project in such a way that my teacher can run a bash script like this:

```sh
unzip virtual_machine.zip
cd virtual_machine
make
./vm
```

This would be incredibly easy if the bash script were:

```sh
unzip virtual_machine.zip
cd virtual_machine
cmake .
make
./vm
```

but that's not the case. I can get it to work if I zip and unzip the files inside my original project, but when I zip, then move the project to a different location, I get a path error.

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/my/project/path/virtual_machine" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

I know that this is because the Makefile no longer lives where it was built but I'm unsure how to allow the makefile to still build the executables even after the whole project has been zipped, moved to a different machine and unzipped.

Any thoughts would be super helpful!! Thanks!

Comment: The makefiles generated by cmake (or any build files) aren't designed to be used the way you're describing.  They have paths to the project directories, both source and build.  You'll have a much easier time biting the bullet and writing makefiles for your teacher.

Comment: As Stephen suggests, the answer is "you can't".  CMake makefiles have paths hardcoded into them all over the place.  The only way to rewrite them is to rerun cmake.  If you can't rerun cmake, you can't use them.

Comment: Ya, I found a very old post on a CMake forum telling me "you can't" about 20 min after posting this but I left it up with some hope that I would find an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your teacher actually has cmake installed you can do what you are asking with a Makefile wrapper for cmake.

Example Makefile:

```
default:
    cmake -S . -B build
    cd build && make

clean:
    rm vm
    rm -r build
```

Example CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.13) 
project (TEST) 

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ..)

add_executable(vm main.c)
```

Comment: That is an awesome solution but I also learned that I'm not allowed to use CMake. So I did the natural thing and wrote a script to translate my cmake environment over to a "normal" make environment... maybe I over engineered it. It's fine.. Thanks anyway!!